# How to fix ternary if React Redirect statement based on web token

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to check if there is a token in localstorage and if so, go to the coorisponding component, if there is not, I would like the page to go to the login page.

If I manually change the "authTokenhas === true" to "authTokenhas !== true" it works correctly so it appears I'm not structuring the if statement correctly?

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Redirect,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';

var authTokenhas = localStorage.getItem('token');


const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (

  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    authTokenhas === true
    ? <Component {...props}/>
    : <Redirect to={{
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { from: props.location }
    }}/>
  )}/>
)

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem exists, because you are comparing `authTokenhas` to true using [strict equality (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity). `'true'` will never strictly equal `true`.

According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem), `localStorage.getItem` will ALWAYS return a [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString), which will never be strictly equal to true. You should either convert the token to a boolean, or turn off strict checking, **and use 0 or 1** (Using strings such as true or false will get you into trouble. (See `console.log(!!'false')`).